# git push --tags trying to push unchanged tags and failing

Tags: git

I am updating a remote git tree with some couple of new tags and this operation successfully completes. Now when I do git push --tags it tries to repush the same tags and gives failure message as `failed to lock`

Note that this tree has many tags in remote. Also I have permissions to push to this tree but I don't have access to the server for performing any clean ups there.

Comment: When you say cleanup what did you try?

Comment: I did not try anything yet. I don't have access to remote server

Comment: Are you saying you tried to push the tags once - it worked, and now when you try to repush the tags, it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, the tag is pushed successfully once, when I try to do git push --tags, it is retrying to push the same tags and fails with `failed to lock` message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a fresh set of tags to the remote, you might want to delete the already existing pushed remote tags:

```
git push <remote_name> :<tag_name>
```

You can then push all the tags once they have been cleaned up.

If you want to push just a single tag name do this: `git push origin <tag_name>`

Comment: The tags it complained on I deleted them explicitly in remote and tried doing git push --tags and it worked. The deleted tags were repushed successfully. Now when I retried git push --tags again I get the same error on couple of tags

Comment: Why don't you just push a single tag then? - `git push origin <tag_name>`

Comment: There is no problem updating the tag one by one. I wanted to know why is git push trying to repush an unchanged tag

Comment: @vishalm `git push --tags` probably attempts to push all tags for two reasons that I can think of - the first is that tags aren't versioned, so `git` doesn't really know if they've been changed or not, and the second is that it's probably more efficient to send all the tags to the remote and let it sort them out than it is to query all the tags from the remote, compare them and figure out which tags to actually send.